# Datetime does not keep 12 hour format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have followed similar threads in order to understand how to convert a variable stored in 24 hour format into 12 hour format. The problem is that, once I try to include the formatted variable in my dataset, which is now treated as a string, the 24 hour format comes back again. Can anybody explain what can I do?  Below you can see the steps that I have taken:

```
data["arrival_time"] = data["arrival_time"].astype('str')
arr = []
for i in data["arrival_time"]:
  if i != "nan":
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%H:%M:%S")
    b = a.strftime("%I:%M %p")
    arr.append(b)
  else:
    arr.append(i)

data["departure_time"] = data["departure_time"].astype('str')
dep = []
for i in data["departure_time"]:
  if i != "nan":
    c = datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%H:%M:%S")
    d = c.strftime("%I:%M %p")
    dep.append(d)
  else:
    dep.append(i)

data["formatted_arrival_time"] = arr
data["formatted_departure_time"] = dep

data["formatted_arrival_time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["formatted_arrival_time"], format = "%I:%M %p", errors = "ignore").dt.time
data["formatted_arrival_time"]
```

The output is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMyl6.png)

Comment: 12- or 24-hour display is a *formatting* option, for dates intended for human consumption. You can't influence the way the `datetime` is *stored*, so if you simply output a `datetime` without specifying a display format you will simply get the default representation.

Answer (score 0):

to_datetime uses the format to parse data, not store it. That's just the default representation of a time. If you want it to be displayed as a 12 hour time, you will need to store it as a string as you had it before pd.to_datetime() or convert it when you want to display the data.

Comment: But if I have to perform some operations, such as take the difference between the formatted departure and arrival times, how can I do that without changing to datetime first? Because for me it is fundamental that I am able to distinguish between 'AM' or 'PM' otherwise the difference in time would be negative

Comment: Exactly, the time format is better. Subtractions between time formats will return a timedelta object. The difference (in most cases) will not be negative. 15:00 - 10:00 = +5 hours. Math is easier with 24 hour time. The exception is overnight flights, which is why you should use a datetime that will also consider the day. You can still determine AM/PM using the conditional time.hour < 12.